# detecting hard subs in video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to find a way to batch scan video files and detect those with hard subs.  I have a very large video collection and want to avoid manual scanning.  I've looked at some OCR stuff but that quickly got too complicated.  Now I'm looking at ffmpeg but not sure if it can do it and definitely don't know how if it can.  I will greatly appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Hardsubs are a part of the video so you'll have to use some sort of OCR. I can think of one exception if the collection was made by a conscientious person who added a language tag to the video stream to indicate hardsub language (as in `Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264` in ffmpeg output), but I don't know how common that is.